# How to protect routes in vuejs using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router

How can I protect the routes globally instead of using this, this works on default and redirects users without token to login

```
 beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const hasToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!hasToken) {
      next('/login'); // Redirect to the login page
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
```

This is my how I get my token

```
 created() {
    this.getTokenFromStorage();
  },
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['currentUser', 'error', 'getToken']),
  },
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getUser', 'getTokenFromStorage']),
  },
```

I get the token in my Vuex store
[image]

How can I just use my `getToken` and access it globally in Vue

Comment: Be aware that this actually does not protect anything. It just redirects the user to the login page, but all the data is still in the app/vuex. If you use the console to add an item to local storage with the key `token`, you can enter any route that is 'protected'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use **Navigation Guards** in Vue Router. Here's the [documentation link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

```
const router = createRouter({ ... });

// use `beforeEach` navigation guard on router
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const hasToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (!hasToken) {
    return '/login'; // Redirect to the login page
  }
});
```